# Using if statement to print whether a String is odd or even in java

Tags: java, if-statement

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner String = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a String:  ");
        String Str1 =String.nextLine();



        String input;
        input = Str1;
        char[] inputArray = input.toCharArray();

        String[] lines = new String[input.length() / 2 + 1];
        int i, u;

        for (i = 0; i < input.length() / 2; i++) {

            char begChar = inputArray[i];
            char endChar = inputArray[input.length() - i - 1];

            int spacesBefore = i;
            int spacesAfter = i;
            int spacesInBetween = input.length() - 2 - 2 * i;

            String line = "";
            for (u = 0; u< spacesBefore; u++) {
                line += " ";
            }
            line += begChar;
            for (u = 0; u < spacesInBetween; u++) {
                line += " ";
            }
            line += endChar;

            lines[i] = line;
        }

        if (input.length() % 2 != 0) {
            String lastLine = "";
            for (u = 0; u < input.length() / 2; u++) {
                lastLine += " ";
            }
            lastLine += inputArray[input.length() / 2];
            lines[input.length() / 2] = lastLine;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < lines.length && lines[i] != null; i++) {
            System.out.println(lines[i]);
        }



        System.out.print("String Length: ");



        System.out.println(Str1.length());}
```

This is where I am having the issue with my code.
I am trying to get this to print whether the user entered String is odd or even. Using Netbeans IDE it keeps telling me that I have a bad operand type int for unary operator '!'. Everything else in the code is working like it should just can't get this to work.

```
 if ( !(Str1.length( ) %0x2))
          System.out.println("The String is odd");
 else
          System.out.println("The String is even");
```

Comment: `if (Str1.length() % 2 != 0)`

Comment: you can't use the ! operator on an integer result which is what you get from using the %. you need to call it on a boolean result

Comment: Unrelated advice: best to *always* use `{}` brackets for your `if`, `else`, loops and so on. Otherwise, if you go ahead and add another line later on, suddenly things will break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!` is an `unary` negation operator that expects a single `boolean` operand. Therefore it can't be applied on an `int`

You should change

```
if ( !(Str1.length( ) %0x2))
          System.out.println("The String is odd");
 else
          System.out.println("The String is even");
```

To this

```
 if (Str1.length() %2 != 0){
          System.out.println("The String is odd");
 }
 else{
          System.out.println("The String is even");
 }
```

`!=` is the operator that checks if the values of two operands are equal or not, if values are not equal then condition becomes true.

Comment: That's not adding any value to the already existing answer and comments. You might want to at least add a bit of explanation and/or references to make it a more useful answer. Check the comments for ideas...

Comment: @domdom ok i'll do

Answer (score 0):

Basically you do this:

```
if (Str1.length() %2 != 0)
```

Comment: You might want to add a bit of an explanation to make this a more useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are attempting to call the ! operator on a integer result from using the % operator which is producing the error you are seeing currently

```
if (!(Str1.length( ) % 0x2))
    System.out.println("The String is odd");
else
    System.out.println("The String is even");
```

What you can do is what was suggested by others. This works because you are comparing your result of using the % operator with 2 which produces a boolean result. Therefore the if statement can evaluate it and determine it to be true or false. With the added ! operator you reverse the result of whatever the expression is inside the parentheses.

```
if (!(Str1.length( ) % 2 != 0))
    System.out.println("The String is odd");
else
    System.out.println("The String is even");
```